# Stream Reader not Reading SuperScript characters

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I am Using StreamReader to import data from Tab Delim Text file to a Data Table called Import Data. For some reasons none of the superScript characters are readable once its imported to the table.

For example If i have a ProductName value "Universal 360° Rotating Finger Ring Holder" in the text file, after import the value becomes like "Universal 360� Rotating Finger Ring Holder" It's same with other characters like " ® , ™ ".

Is there something to do with my code?

```
Public Function FillData(ByVal Fpath As String) As Boolean
        Dim XRead As System.IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(FilePath)
        Dim XLine As String = Nothing
        Dim XSplitLine() As String
        Dim i As Integer = ImportedData.Rows.Count + 1
        Try
            XRead.ReadLine()
            XLine = XRead.ReadLine()
            Do Until XLine Is Nothing

                XLine = i & vbTab & XLine & vbTab & FilePath
                XSplitLine = XLine.Split(CType(vbTab, Char()))

                ImportedData.Rows.Add(XSplitLine)
                XLine = XRead.ReadLine
                i += 1
            Loop
            XRead.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End Try

        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: What encoding is the input file stored in?  Is it some form of ASCII or UTF?  Does it contain a BOM at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Seeing � back tells you that you are using the [wrong Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_).  Encoding.Default tends to be the next correct guess if the file did not cross too many borders while traveling to your machine.  Encouraging the programmer that wrote the program that created this file to use utf8 is highly recommended.

Comment: @Steven Doggart,  Test file is encoded in ANSI.

Comment: ANSI isn't really a specific enough term.  There are any number of encodings that people refer to as ANSI.  Do you know which one it is specifically?

Comment: You need to know the ANSI code page.

Comment: It's *Encode in ANSI* doesn't mean anything. If someone used a Local CodePage, you may know what page that is, if you know the source of the file. Try with your current CodePage, if you think it could be the same.

Comment: @J.Doe Does it work with `Dim XRead As System.IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(filepath, Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))`?

Comment: Andrew Morton.. It is also working. Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim XRead As System.IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(FilePath,Text.encoding.DefaultEncoding)
```

should be able to read this correctly.